# Remove tracker javascript after </html> elemnt

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

After moving app to shared hosting i see i have new javascript code after `</html>` tag. This code create big problems for ajax requests and other.
I try to found script but i cant. I use Laravel framework and i have only custom js abd CDN `jquery, bootstrap, dataTables and Select2` plugin included in page but on every request this code is here.

**What i try:**

- First i try to put opened comment `<!--` but not working.
- Second what i try to create `<div id="deleteThis">` and with javascript to remove all inner html with body onload event. Not work js is still there.
- Third what i try is using `jQuery` `$("#deleteThis").remove()`. not working
  Check photo to see [image]

Does somebody have idea to remove this? I cant reinstall project becouse project is so big.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to open the site without chrome extension (via private browsing mode for example), it already happened to me that extensions add JavaScript in my files and that it causes problem because it is a development environment.

The "live server" can also add scripts, maybe it is involved. (But it seems to me not very probable).

Comment: I found problem. Nothing in code was injected. Problem is in chrome.  Probobly some extension mlawere. I change browser and all work fine. I cant beleve i spend to many hours for nothing. Deam. Thanks